# How do I write an expression that adds y for a set of linear equations for different value intervals of x?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm not sure if this forum is overkill for my simple question, but here goes :-)

I have a set of simple linear functions that are defined for intervals of X with decreasing slopes as x grows:

y = 0,25x for x = 0 - 5

y = 0,20x for x = 6-15

y = 0,15x for x = 16 - 25

y = 0,10x for x = 26 - 35

and so on...
What is challenging me, is that I need to sum the y values for the highest x-value in each interval up until the interval for which my x belongs to. So for example if x = 23, I need to first find y for x = 5 and add that to y for x = 15 and then finally add that to y=0,15*23.

Can someone provide me with a stricter algorithm that outlines the process of finding a given value of y?

Could I somehow express this with a ∑-symbol?

I hope my question makes sense, my math is very rusty, I'll gladly try to make it clearer!

Thanks
Christian

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: What happens for x in between 5 and 6?

Comment: Good point, I could define the intervals with '<' and '>', but because of it's practical application, it doesn't have to be defined for values between integers. (It's dealing with the number of students signed up for a course, so no decimal number of students!). Can you help me with a way of achieving what I am looking to do? Or is it still unclear what I am trying to do?

Comment: I think a clarification would help. Also if answering specific people please use the @ so they get notified and don't stumble across it per accident.